Horror movie about a family of two kids who get lost and fake kids return instead
I'm looking for a horror film about a family that traveled to town that is cursed by demons. They had 2 kids, a girl named Marica. I don't remember the boy's name.
As usual a weird guy in a petrol station tells them that something is wrong with this town. They let the kids out of the car for you know and they disappeared when the parents woke up and the kids didn't return. They called the cops but the parents heard that a guy called Lossio saw their children before they disappeared. They sneak up to his trailer and the husband puts a knife on that guy's neck and wakes him up asking him about their kids. And he said he didn't know, until the mother searching his trailer found bloody panties so the husband cuts his throat because they thought he did something to them.
At some point they find them, but they don't know yet that these aren't their kids. They act weird and the school calls the mother and once she decides to trace their movements she finds out they ride the bus to a cave. There she finds that kids' dead corpses and realizes they are possessed and their real kids are dead inside that cave and those kids at home are not the real ones. She talks to the guy in the station and he says that his daughter was killed by a demon and they existed since the start of the town and Indians said that the cave where the kids were in when they got lost is cursed.
She shows her husband their bodies and he shoots her with a gun at the end of the movie, I think they became possessed because both returned to the petrol station.
Also one thing, I took a quick look at the cast and the only one I can remember is Kent McCord. I tried to search for his roles in horror movies but it was irrelevant to that one. 

Sounds like "Here Comes the Devil"

"A married couple lose their children while on a family trip near some caves in Tijuana. The kids eventually reappear without explanation, but it becomes clear that they are not who they used to be, that something terrifying has changed them."

Preview:



